# Blurred background for a div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am making an image library. I have a div inside which I kept an image. Now I want the div to have the same image as a background but blurred. I used the common CSS3 blur option but all the child elements gets blurred too (in my case the image). Am new to JavaScript, so would love a simple code.

Comment: Update your question with the html/css you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is more of a CSS question if anything. What I am guessing you are doing is:

HTML:

```
<div class="parentElement">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parentElement { filter: blur(15px); }
```

Or in JS:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("parentElement")[0].style.filter = "blur(15px)";
```

**This will blur the background as well as all elements in parentElement.**

The best solution to only blur the background of the element would be to create a separate child inside your parentElement for your background (or whatever you called the class with the background) and set the styles to that like so:

HTML:

```
<div class="parentElement">
    <div class="background"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.background { filter: blur(15px); }
```

Or in JS:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("background")[0].style.filter = "blur(15px)";
```

You will need to make the class "background" act like a background and to do so you will need to make it full width of the parent element and position it absolute.

CSS:

```
.parentElement { position:relative; }

.background { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; filter: blur(15px); }
```

Comment: I know. But its kindof necessary to have it as a child.

Comment: @ArchanBhattacharjee I am sorry but I don't understand what you mean. Do you mean it is necessary to have the background on the parent element? If you provide an example of your code I might be able to provide a better answer.